# How to set property name with dot from docker compose?

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I need to set environment variable with name like `com.somesite.apikey`.
I was trying these variants im my *doccker-compose.yml*

```
environment:
      com.somesite.apikey: 98989897979
      com_somesite_apikey: 98798709089
```

But method `System.getProperty("com.somesite.apikey")` returns empty.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: "com_somesite_apikey" this should work. Did you try to execute 'echo $com_somesite_apikey' against the container.

Comment: It works with underscore notation, but my code need to access property using dot notation like in this case `System.getProperty("com.somesite.apikey")`

Comment: I think you cant, because dot is not a valid character in a shell identifier. If you try to 'echo $com.somesite.apikey' it will print '.somesite.apikey'

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring Boot documentation on setting properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) notes that the "spelling" of environment variables must be

> Environment Variables: Upper case format with underscore as the delimiter.

So you should be able to set

```
environment:
  COM_SOMESITE_APIKEY: 98798709089
```

Comment: This works only when access property using `@Value("${com.somesite.apikey}")`

Comment: But when i trying to get property in this way `System.getProperty("com.somesite.apikey")` it does not work

Comment: Environment variables and system properties are different, you'd use `System.getenv()` to get an environment variable.

Comment: ok, in other words, i have i code which accessing property by calling `System.getProperty("com.somesite.apikey")`.

What i should to specify in docker compose file to set property with this name?